# Installing/booting Ubuntu (any version) from usb on Acer One 10 S1002

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I have an Acer One 10 S1002 (4in1), wich comes with W10 preinstalled. 
For usual, booting ubuntu doesn´t require high complications, but in this case, someone thought that:
-> using a 32 uefi in 64 proccesor
-> restrict at max the BIOS
-> Set max security on boot
was a good idea.

I think I thried everything I can get from google (rufus+ub15.04x64+gpt), but nothing seems do anything to make the USB key recognizable for the BIOS boot menu.

Any idea?

Comment: change the parameter fro gpt to mbr partition table, and FREE SPACE FROM WINDOWS BEFORE BOOTING

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create UEFI-only bootable USB live media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media)